# topologies on globalizations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I am reading notes by David Vogan on Unitary representations and Complex analysis ([pdf](http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/veniceCORR.pdf) / [dvi)](http://www-math.mit.edu/~dav/veniceCORR.dvi).

The setting is as follows (page 23): Let $X$ be a $(\mathfrak{g},K)$-module and let $X(\mu)$ denote its $\mu$-isotypical component for $\mu\in\hat{K}$. On each $X(\mu)$ there is $K$-invariant scalar product $\|\  \|_\mu$.

Various globalizations of $X$ are given as spaces of sequences $(x(\mu))_{\mu\in\hat{K}}$ with certain conditions on  $\| x(\mu)\| _\mu$. These conditions also lead to a canonical topology on the globalizations.

Vogan also mentions that even $X = \bigoplus_{\mu\in\hat{K}} X(\mu)$ itself and $\Pi_{\mu\in\hat{K}} X(\mu) = X^{-K}$ have canonical topologies.

Q1: How are these topologies defined?

Q2: Are the inclusions $X\subseteq X^{\text{glob}} \subseteq X^{-K}$ continuous with dense images?

Q3: Consider Hermitian symmetric case and complexifications. There is a parabolic subgroup of $G^\mathbb{C}$ given by $P=K^\mathbb{C}U$ with $U$ abelian such that the compact symmetric space $G/K$ is isomorphic to $G^\mathbb{C}/P$. Can one extend continuously the action of $K$ on to $P$ for $X$, $X^\text{glob}$ and $X^{-K}$?

Comment: For Q1, the topology is "just" the (canonical) topology on a countable product or coproduct of finite-dimensional topological vector spaces ("countable" guarantees that the coproduct will be locally convex). Perhaps Chapter 2 of Taylor's notes would be helpful (http://www.math.utah.edu/~taylor/LCS.pdf).